# Sending Multiple mails using excel cell values using VP

Tags: vba, excel

I have an old script to send multiple mails from excel using Cell values, 1st cell is the E-Mail address, 2nd is Mail Subject, 3rd contains the mail body, it doesn't work anymore!! HELP PLZ

---

```
Sub CreateMail()

   Dim objOutlook As Object
   Dim objMail As Object
   Dim rngEntry As Range
   Dim rngEntries As Range

   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set rngEntries = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")

   For Each rngEntry In rngEntries
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objMail
            .To = rngEntry.Value
            .Subject = rngEntry.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Body = rngEntry.Offset(0, 2).Value
           '.Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value
           .Send '.Display or .Save
        End With
   Next rngEntry

   Set objOutlook = Nothing
   Set objMail = Nothing
   Set rngEntry = Nothing
   Set rngEntries = Nothing

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Its really important to ask questions properly here. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: That is not VB.NET, but VBA.

Comment: the error is "Run Time error '-2147467259 (800004005)':
Outlook doesn't recognize one or more names."

Comment: Do you have the outlook reference checked in Tools > References?  Also, to repeat David's assertion, are you trying to do this in VB (VP)???  Because this code is VBA.

Comment: I'm Sorry for the Typo, I meant VBA already :), this code I used it like 5 years ago when I first had it, but today it doesn't work with the error above, note that I do use many other VBA scripts within the outlook itself to manage the bulk tasks..

Answer (score 0):

Your vba code does send emails to any names in column B.  However, when it hits the first row with no data it attempts to send an email without a "To:" party.  This fix will stop the subroutine when it hits an empty cell in column B:

```
Sub CreateMail()

   Dim objOutlook As Object
   Dim objMail As Object
   Dim rngEntry As Range
   Dim rngEntries As Range

   Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
   Set rngEntries = ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")

   For Each rngEntry In rngEntries
   If rngEntry.Value <> "" Then '  ADD THIS LINE HERE
        Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With objMail
            .To = rngEntry.Value
            .Subject = rngEntry.Offset(0, 1).Value
            .Body = rngEntry.Offset(0, 2).Value
           '.Attachments.Add rngEntry.Offset(0, 3).Value
           .Send '.Display or .Save
        End With
    Else  '  ADD THIS LINE HERE
        Exit Sub  '  ADD THIS LINE HERE
    End If  '  ADD THIS LINE HERE
   Next rngEntry

   Set objOutlook = Nothing
   Set objMail = Nothing
   Set rngEntry = Nothing
   Set rngEntries = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Sounds like a data problem.  It worked fine on my test sheet